# Mathematical Operator to flip a vector

Tags: operator-theory

Is there a mathematical operator which flips a vector from left to right (or up to down). Say
\begin{align}
a = [1~ 2~ 3]\quad\text{and}\quad b = [3~ 2~ 1]
\end{align}
I'd like to have
\begin{align}
a = \sigma\circ b 
\end{align}
where $\sigma$ is the flip operator. How would you define it? Or does the operator might exists already and I'm just not aware?

Comment: Multiply it by an [anti-diagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-diagonal_matrix) unit matrix

Comment: @Henry it it also called exchange matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of any such operator, however, you could multiply your vector by the matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 &1 \\ 
 0& 1 &0 \\ 
 1&0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$

and then take the transpose.

Comment: Your matrix is not an operator ?

Comment: No. In fact, I don't know of any operator that will work, I was just trying to helpful and my reputation score isn't high enough to just post a comment yet.

Comment: @someone: Your matrix may not _be_ an operator, but it certainly _corresponds_ to one. In this context, the term "operator" is simply another word for "linear transformation" between two vector spaces, and left multiplication with your matrix defines such an operator.